# How to track One2many field in Odoo12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to log the changes on a One2many field using `track_visibility='onchange'`. But it's not working.

Here is the code:

**respartner.py**

```
   bank_account_ids = fields.One2many('customer.bank.account','partner_id',
    string='Account',track_visibility="onchange")
```

**account.py**

```
  _name = 'customer.bank.account'
_description = 'Partner Bank Account Details'

partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string="Partner")
name = fields.Integer(string="Account Number",required=True,
    track_visibility="onchange")
bank_id = fields.Many2one('partner.bank',string="Bank",track_visibility="onchange")
branch_id = fields.Many2one('partner.bank.branch',string="Branch",
    track_visibility="onchange")
```

Comment: AFAIK Odoo is not providing tracked changes of subrecords to its parent records. We had the same requirement for Odoo 10 and solved it by overriding the tracking functionality by posting a tracking note on the parent record if exisiting. Just look into mail.thread.message_track(), that's the point to start ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, No need to touch ORM. Try this

```
class ParentClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'parent.class'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']

    child_ids = fields.One2many('child.class', 'relational_field_name_id')


class ChildClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'child.class'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']

    name = fields.Char(tracking=True) # Note that tracking is true here
    relational_field_name_id = fields.Many2one('parent.class')

    def write(self, vals):
        super().write(vals)
        if set(vals) & set(self._get_tracked_fields()):
            self._track_changes(self.relational_field_name_id)

    def _track_changes(self, field_to_track):
        if self.message_ids:
            message_id = field_to_track.message_post(body=f'<strong>{ self._description }:</strong> { self.display_name }').id
            trackings = self.env['mail.tracking.value'].sudo().search([('mail_message_id', '=', self.message_ids[0].id)])
            for tracking in trackings:
                tracking.copy({'mail_message_id': message_id})
```

If you just want to track on relational and not current model then use **write** instead of **copy** method

```
tracking.write({'mail_message_id': message_id})
```

And for delete and create you can just use **message_post** inside **create** and **unlink** method

```
self.message_post(body=f'<strong>{ self._description }:</strong> { self.display_name } created/deleted')
```